# OpenVPN Access Server With VPN Gateway Other only Gateway IP is reachable

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, gateway

I'm trying to setup OpenVPN with Vpn Gateway so I could access my local LAN using this gateway

I'm using OpenVPN Access Server 
I created 2 clients one as VPN gateway and one for my computer

I'm using Ubuntu 18 as VPN gateway 
after installing open VPN on ubuntu and connect to VPN using gateway config 
connection established successfully

but from the other side, after the connection established I was only able to ping the gateway LAN IP

my private LAN subnet
192.168.1.0/24

my VPN subnet
5.5.5.0/24

after the connection successfully established I was only able to ping 
192.168.1.112 which is the gateway local IP
but actually there are more than 10 other devices on the same network

this is the nmap result

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-08-05 00:25 EEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.112
Host is up (0.19s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 24.53 seconds
```

and this is the vpn gateway config
[image: open vpn gateway config]

and this is the client config 
[image: open vpn user config]

Answer (score 0):

You need to give static routing on router having gateway ip to vpn client ip address to destination i.e. your lan